# Ajax customer login magento and wordpress

Tags: magento-1.9, ajax, wordpress

I am trying to login on both cms at once , ajax file is working in chrome, that is in magento root , but not working in firefox . any help appreciated .

```
jQuery('#mg_login').on('submit', function(e) {


                  var email= jQuery('#log').val();
                  var pwd= jQuery('#pwd').val();
                   alert("email--"+email+" password--"+ pwd);
                  jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: "password=" + pwd + "&email=" + email,
            url: "http://aaaaaaa/p/mg_cust_login.php",
            success: function (result)
            {

                         alert(result); 

            }

        });

     });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use To fetch store code on the ajax file at the top